# Inserting query results into a table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to create a sign in which writes to multiple tables which are linked by the primary key of each table. It therefore queries what it has writted to the first table to find the auto incremented primary key to insert into the second table.

However I keep getting an error saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 79

but I cannot find the error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    <?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE REGISTRATION PAGE.

# Set page title and display header section.
    $page_title = 'Register' ;
    include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

    `enter code here`# Check form submitted.
    `enter code here`if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )
    {
      # Connect to the database.
      require ('connect_db.php'); 

      # Initialize an error array.
      $errors = array();

      # Check for a username.
      if ( empty( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) )
      { $errors[] = 'Enter your username.' ; }
      else
      { $q1 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) ) ; }


       # Check for an email address:
       if ( empty( $_POST[ 'email' ] ) )
      { $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.'; }
      else
      { $q2 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $_POST[ 'email' ] ) ) ; } 


      # Check for a unit name:
      if ( empty( $_POST[ 'unitusername' ] ) )
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your unit name.'; }
  else
  { $q4 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $_POST[ 'unitusername' ] ) ) ; }


  # Check for a password and matching input passwords.
  if ( !empty($_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) )
  {
    if ( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] != $_POST[ 'pass2' ] )
    { $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match.' ; }
    else
    { $q3 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) ) ; }
  }
  else { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; }

  # Check if username already registered.
  if ( empty( $errors ) )
  {
    $q = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$q1'" ;
    $r = @mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;
    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) != 0 ) $errors[] = 'Username already registered. <a href="login.php">Login</a>' ;
  }

    # Check if unit already registered.
  if ( empty( $errors ) )
  {
    $q = "SELECT unitusername FROM unit WHERE unitusername='$q4'" ;
    $r = @mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;
    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) != 0 ) $errors[] = 'Unit already registered. <a href="login.php">Login</a>' ;
  }

  # On success register user inserting into 'unit' database table.
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "INSERT INTO unit (unitusername, mainuserid) VALUES ('$q4', '0' )";
    $r = @mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;}


    # Find unit id from newly registered unit 
    $q5 = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT unitid FROM unit WHERE unitusername = '$q4'");

    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($q5))
  {

  # On success register user inserting into 'users' database table.
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, usertype, unitid) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', SHA1('$q3'), '1', '$row5['unitid']')";
    $r = @mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;
   }}


    # Find unit id from newley registered unit 
    $q6 = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = '$q1'");


    #put the main userid into the unit table
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "UPDATE unit SET mainuserid = '$q6' WHERE unitid = '$q5'";
    $r = @mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;
   }    

   #populate the unituser table
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
   {
    $q = "INSERT INTO unituser (unitid, userid) VALUES ('$q5', '$q6')";
    $r = @mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q );



  echo '<h1>Registered!</h1><p>You are now registered.</p><p><a href="login.php">Login</a></p>';
    # Close database connection.
    mysqli_close($dbc); 

    # Display footer section and quit script:
    include ('includes/footer.html'); 
    exit(); }

  # Or report errors.
  else 
  {
    echo '<h1>Error!</h1><p id="err_msg">The following error(s) occurred:<br>' ;
    foreach ( $errors as $msg )
    { echo " - $msg<br>" ; }
    echo 'Please try again.</p>';
    # Close database connection.
    mysqli_close( $dbc );
  }  
}
?>

<!-- Display body section with sticky form. -->
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="registernewunit.php" method="post">
<p>username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']; ?>"> 
Unit Name: <input type="text" name="unitusername" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['unitusername'])) echo $_POST['unitusername']; ?>"></p>
<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" size="50" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>"></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pass1'])) echo $_POST['pass1']; ?>" >
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pass2'])) echo $_POST['pass2']; ?>"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: So.. where is line 79?

Comment: Please point here the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 79

stems from

`'$row5['unitid']'` which should be `'$row5[unitid]'` in VALUES.